# Facing issues with H2O MOJO deployment using sparkling water on Google Dataproc

Tags: h2o, sparkling-water, h2o.ai

I am trying to migrate a model from Hadoop to GCP. Model MOJO will not be retrained. I am running the model in Dataproc using Airflow spark submit.
Source data format matches with Hadoop source and everything. While running the model, I am getting this error:

```
Caused by: hex.genmodel.easy.exception.PredictUnknownCategoricalLevelException: Unknown categorical level (my_column,Y)
```

This column has the same values as we have on Hadoop, and in there everything works fine.
Model was created on H20 version `3.30.0.4` and MOJO version is `1.4`.

While running the dataproc cluster I am using `"PIP_PACKAGES": "h2o_pysparkling_3.1"`

Not sure what the issue is? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

can you please try enabling `convertUnknownCategoricalLevelsToNa`?

Here is the related documentation:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-release/sparkling-water/spark-3.1/3.42.0.2-1-3.1/doc/deployment/load_mojo.html#customizing-the-mojo-settings